# Why does this cause an ArithmeticException in C# when SQLPlus is all ok

Tags: c#, oracle, date, sqlplus, overflowexception

I have a view connecting 4 tables

```
CREATE VIEW BookCopyInfo 
AS
SELECT
  bc.BookCopyID, b.BookTitle, m.FirstName || ' ' || m.LastName AS BorrowedBy,
  l.expectedReturnDate, (SYSDATE - l.expectedReturnDate) AS NoOfDaysLate
FROM Book b, Member m, Lending l, BookCopy bc
WHERE b.BookID = bc.BookID AND l.MemberID = m.MemberID
  AND l.BookCopyID = bc.BookCopyID
```

There is a small date arithmetic going on that finds how many days was a book late

```
(SYSDATE - l.expectedReturnDate)
```

When i do a `SELECT * FROM BookCopyInfo`, i get rows like

```
4  | Human Computer Interaction | Alan Paul | 10-JUL-10  | -13.642292
```

So it is correct and -13 is the correct answer actually.

`DESC BookCopyInfo` returns

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ---------------

 BOOKCOPYID                                NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 BOOKTITLE                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100)
 BORROWEDBY                                         VARCHAR2(126)
 EXPECTEDRETURNDATE                        NOT NULL DATE
 NOOFDAYSLATE                                       NUMBER(38)
```

However in C#

```
DataTable dtBookInfo = new DataTable();
da = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM BookCopyInfo", con);
da.Fill(dtBookInfo);
```

catches an exception in the da.Fill line

> OverflowException was unhandled by user code.
>   Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Why does it work fine in SQLPlus but fails in C#? :S

Comment: Does it work if you replace `(SYSDATE - l.expectedReturnDate)` by a constant (say `0 AS NoOfDaysLate` in your view? Just to make sure the date calculation is actually causing your problem...

Comment: Yes. The application runs fine with 0 AS NoOfDaysLate :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it has to with SQL-Number data type. You can try the following option..

1) .... Round((SYSDATE - l.expectedReturnDate),2 ) ...

2) Convert the data type of "NoOfDaysLate" to integer.

Comment: How do perform the conversion in Oracle 11g?

Answer (score 1):

IF you are just interested in some part of the difference between the two dates, then you should use DateDiff instead...

Eg:
DATEDIFF(yy, startDate, endDate) YearsPassedSinceStart

returns the no. of years passed since the start date.

Similarly to find number of months, use 'm' as the datepart or 'd' to determine no. of days.

Comment: DATEDIFF is not an Oracle function...that is SQL Server.